# Ubuntu 14.04 fails to recognize FakeRaid volume

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64 on a new machine based on an Asus Z10PE-D8 motherboard with Intel FakeRaid. The boot drive is an SSD with dual boot Windows 7 and Linux. I also have two additional hard drives that I want to use in RAID-0 in Linux (don't need the volume in Windows). I created the RAID-0 volume in the BIOS setup and Windows properly sees the volume (can partition/format, everything looks good). I can't make Linux to recognize the volume. I tried to use `dmraid` first, as suggested in [FakeRaidHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto), but it looks like outdated information. `dmraid` recognizes the volume but only sees 1.2 TB instead of 5 TB. I then tried to use `mdadm`, which apparently is the current standard for FakeRaid under Ubuntu 14.04, but `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan` apparently does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks I found the solution. I have to tell `mdadm` to use external metadata, as detailed [here](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#External_Metadata)